# Force input fill str

Tags: jquery

I want to format the input like `XX.X.X` example when user type `10000 => 10.0.0`, and if user type only `10` it should adding `.0` format to `10.0.0` , how can do that ?

```js
    function format(str) {
      var length = 1,
        separator = ".",
        count = 0,
        result = str.split('').reduceRight((a, c) => {
          if (count === length) {
            a.push(separator);
            count = 1;
          } else count++;
          a.push(c);
          return a;
        }, []).reverse().join('');

        return result;
    }  

    $(document).on("input", "#version", function() {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'');


        this.value = format(this.value);
        console.log(this.value.length);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use a jQuery plugin, try the ready solution [inputmask](https://plugins.jquery.com/jquery.inputmask/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mask-version').inputmask("99.9.9");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/5.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="version" class="mask-version" />
```